# How to create a dynamic web project in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

How to create a dynamic web project in Eclipse Juno for Tomcat 6? There is no option for creating a dynamic project in File->New.

Answer (score 0):

You need the  "Ecplipse Java Web Developer Tools" plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

Download Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1